# Windows Server 2012 won't unload DLL in a process

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I've created a program that creates a thread, loads a DLL there (LoadLibrary), calls one function in this DLL and unloads it using FreeLibrary.

LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary do not return any error codes, but ProcessHacket2 shows that this DLL still exists in memory. I've verified that my code does not reference this library.

After some time my code repeats these actions and another instance of this DLL appears in the process memory.

If my code will repeats these actions again and again a new instance will remain in RAM. Allocated virtual memory will growth.

I cannot repeat this problem on my development machine and other test computers. Only on one specific server.

It looks like (libmysql.dll):
[image]

Comment: `another instance of this DLL appears in the process memory.` dll can be loaded to process only once

Comment: Yes, I know. But ProcessHacker on this computer shows several instances.

Comment: Thats more likely an artifact of "process hacker" than windows deciding its going to load the same library multiple times.

Comment: normally we cannot load (with *LoadLibrary* or low level api) same dll several times - will be only once loaded and then returned already loaded base. of course possible with some hacks map the same dll several times, but this already not normal. without reproduce situation or debug on target comp hard say something

Comment: Virtual memory growths and does not reduce. After few hours I get the "Out of memory" error. On a test computer with same OS in our lab the PH shows that library load/unloads every time.

Comment: @HelenDowns: Windows is pretty reliable by now. But if that DLL calls `new` to allocate some memory when it's loaded, and fails to call `delete` when it's unloaded, then the CRT will leak that data. The CRT _has_ to, because it can't know if that memory is now managed by a `std::shared_pr` somewhere in user code. Memory allocations belong to a process, not a DLL.

Comment: If I close the program a memory profiler does not show memory leaks. Usually it catches everything.

Comment: Normally windows will only load a dll with a name once, but you can force multipel loads by passing explicit fully qualified paths to LoadLibrary (or setting up different Activation Contexts). In the presented screenshot, we can SEE the dlls have different base addresses so something is forcing the normal rule to fail - perhaps they are being extracted into temp folders with unique names and loaded from there?

Comment: Extremely strange. I want to see how it is possible :) first of all, you can use api monitor, like http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor and watch all .dll load/unload funcyion. Loadlibrary/loadlibraryex/freelibrary. And try to find some error,etc. As a workaround, you can try to find all instance of .dll in your process and upload it manually. You can start from this code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686849(v=vs.85).aspx in CreateToolhelp32Snapshot th32ProcessID can be zero to indicate your process

Comment: The DLL is located in the program folder. My code does not change its file name or something else. I've tried API monitor. There is nothing abnormal or unexpected. All calls in one thread. Number of LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary calls is equal. GetModuleHandle is not used.

Comment: 1. Try Process Explorer instead of "process hacker". 2 Try to load/unload another dll (as simple as possible).